# AssertionError: - Expected [ true ] to be [ true ]. in protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, assertion

I have faced with this assertion error in protractor when i try to compare a check box value in a form using below.
`expect( page.H3_elements.get(0).isSelected()).toBe(true);`
I'm getting the error `- Expected [ true ] to be [ true ].`

Comment: that is weird. Try to use .toBeTruthy()

Answer (score 0):

**Eventually** property should help

```
expect(page.H3_elements.get(0).isSelected()).to.eventually.be.true;
```

The most powerful extension provided by Chai as Promised is the eventually property. With it, you can transform any existing Chai assertion into one that acts on a promise:

```
return Promise.resolve(2 + 2).should.eventually.equal(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution for checkboxes is: `expect(page.H3_elements.get(0).isSelected()).toBeTruthy();`